# Ignore default libraries in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'd like to be able to tell the debugger not to drill down into default libraries in C++.  (I use both VS 2003 and VS 2010, depending on the project.)  I almost never get any useful information out of this, and it's really tedious having to step through the default code.

For example, I pretty much never have to watch the code that changes a string literal into a std::string when it's passed as a function parameter, nor do I have to watch as that string is then compared to another string, destructed, or whatever.  Having to step out every time the debugger starts bringing me down one of those rabbit holes is pretty annoying.

C# doesn't seem to have this problem - I only see my own code in the debugger and don't get bogged down in obscure default library code which I'm never going to change, and which is pretty close to unreadable anyhow.  I just wish I could have this in C++ as well.  It's one thing if there's actually an error (though that usually isn't very useful - better would be to have the error point to the line in my code that led down to where that error occurred).  But stepping through when there's no problems with the code is almost never useful.

Comment: There is no 'Step over'?  It is useful sometimes to get into the lib code, if only to check that the parameters are correct inside the call.

Comment: he probably refers to the scenario when you want to step into a function, but before you reach that function you'll have to step through some default constructors for whatever is passed as parameter to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio:
Solution Properties -> Debug Source files -> "Do not look into these source files"

Whenever the debugger takes you to a useless location that you don't want to see, you can add it there and it will be ignored.

Comment: That's just not how it works.  That list is auto-populated when you click Cancel at the debugger prompt to locate a source file.  Filling the list pre-emptively requires thousands of files.

Comment: I noticed there's a "Search these paths for source files" list here, that points to some default library locations.  If I remove these, will it ignore the libraries and only show my own code?  (And could this break other things?  Admittedly there might be SOME rare occasions when I'd need to see lib code, so I'd prefer just an easy check-box to switch for those special situations, rather than having to delete those lines, then find them again when I need them, every time...

Comment: yeah you could try that as well but I think it will then prompt you for the location of the libraries, lol. not sure :). This issue never bothered me though...just press shift+F11 whever you're in one of those "places"